# How to recreate this bevel with ledge profile?

Tags: table-saw, router

I'm wanting to build a display case like the one pictured, however I'm not sure how the 'ledge' at the top of the bevel is done.

I initially thought it would be router with chamfer bit and maybe table saw to do the notched ledge... Or it could be a router bit with an odd shape?

I can't quite get my head around it.

I have a jobsite tablesaw that I'm pretty new to, but I do also have my router.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are *many* different ways to get that profile, not One True Way.

- Could all be done with a tablesaw
- Could all be done with a shaper or router bit in one pass (faster to do, but more expensive and less generally useful)
- Could all the done with two different router/shaper bits (slower to do, but more genererally useful)
- Could all be done with hand planes.

None is more valid than another, one *generally* picks the method to suit the tools one has, unless following the siren song of suiting the tool you *want an excuse to buy.*

Comment: What kind of router bit would one need to get such a profile?

Comment: A 45 and a straight cutter (or rabbet cutter, depending which direction you attack from) using some sort of fence or bearing - router table most conventionally (and probably more safely.) Freehand with bearings *could* be done with the right bits and bearings. Might want to cut the rabbet first, depending on your bit selection. A big lock mitre bit that you only use the nose and tongue section of, with the tongue section cutting the rabbet.

Comment: If you do it all on the tablesaw, plan your cut sequence and make at least one spare long piece. (Hint: cut the flats after the bevel.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal I don't know why all I could think about was doing it all in one pass. I'm an idiot XD Of course, you could make a pass with a rebate or straight cutter as you suggested and then a chamfer bit. I have all of these, so I might give it a go on some scrap this week :-)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I just got my jobsite saw and don't want to lose my fingers just yet XD

Comment: @physicsboy — fingers are good. They always say, “know where your fingers are while cutting, lest you have to find them in a pile of sawdust later”.

Comment: Yes, this exactly!

Comment: @physicsboy, as a useful mindset thing for the future when you see a profile that you've never seen before (especially an old one) it is best not to think router bit but instead a combination of cuts/milling operations done in a specific sequence. It's extremely common for atypical or unusual profiles (or historical profiles being recreated) to be done this way, with a combo of basic cuts and/or router passes. Note that the sequence can be important (*order of operations*) to achieving a given end result as if you do cut B or C first it may make cut A impossible or much more difficult. [contd]

Comment: @physicsboy, if you have any hand planes I encourage you to try to do this by hand, it's excellent practice if you have little experience using them. It can be done with any plane within reason, from a block plane through to a no. 5, even on fairly small workpieces. If your TS has a tilting blade do the 'mitre' cut so that it leaves the small flat at the edge. In both cases leaving the flat edges (that would already be there on the starting piece) saves an additional operation, and in the case of the TS might additionally leave an important bearing surface.

Comment: @Graphus yes I understand that the order of operations can be very important. No use adding paint before priming etc.

Comment: OT, I know you’ll approach the tablesaw with caution. My biggest best advice would be to avoid messing with tiny pieces generally. For example, for your stock, you might think that cutting two of them out of a 2x2 is a good idea. It’s not ideal. I’d cut them out of a 2x8, alternating bevel and 90° cuts (with the blade tilted away from the fence). If you didn’t feel like you had the precision (all the pieces have to match perfectly!), cut one long strip that makes 4 sides.